# Java - Timeout long running Callable Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, future, executorservice, callable

```
public class FutureGetTimeoutTest {

    private static final ExecutorService THREAD_POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        List<String> respList = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        futures.add(THREAD_POOL.submit(new CallableTask(1L)));
        futures.add(THREAD_POOL.submit(new CallableTask(2L)));
        futures.add(THREAD_POOL.submit(new CallableTask(3L)));

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(start);
        for (Future<String> future : futures) {
            try {
                respList.add(future.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                /*
                 * Timeout time for 2nd Task starts only at the end of 1st Task Timeout
                 * and so 2nd task is able to run for 20s and 3rd task for 30s!
                 */
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end);
        System.out.println(end - start);
        System.out.println(respList);

    }

}

class CallableTask implements Callable<String> {

    private long ipAddressL;

    public CallableTask(long ipAddressL) {
        this.ipAddressL = ipAddressL;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        if (ipAddressL == 1) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            /* Imagine a DB operation taking more time. */
            return "1";
        } else if (ipAddressL == 2) {
            Thread.sleep(20000);
            return "2";
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(30000);
            return "3";
        }

    }
}
```

I want to return a empty string or just terminate the thread or throw a TimeoutException from within each task if **each** task takes more than 10 seconds individually.

Say 1st thread takes 10s, `Future.get()` will wait for 10s and then timeout. I will catch the exception and proceed the iteration for 2nd future object. Say 2nd thread is not completed by this time (which means it ran for 10s while 1st thread ran and is still running), now `Future.get()` on 2nd thread will wait for another 10s and so a total of 20s and so on for subsequent threads.

```
future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) (1 sec),
```

will ensure 10s limit for the whole operation but I need a 10s limit on the whole operation by having a 10s limit on each individual concurrent task.

Comment: Did you research the available network timeout settings on `Connection` and `Statement` objects?  You cannot explicitly cancel queries but can catch `SQLTimeOut` exceptions.

Comment: No telling why the downvotes but maybe the code example could be minimized and made a little more abstract.  Always appreciate the downvotes though,  one pity upvote will give you as many points as 5 downvotes and you are likely to get them on questions that shouldn't have been downvoted. As for the problem,Jim is right, set your sql timeout and catch the exception it throws.

Comment: Why down vote guys? SQL is within a jar library. I can't modify or any connection parameters. I only have access to threads. Closest I got is Timeout of Future.get(). But major issue is that timeout of 1st Future.get() will impact subsequent Future.get() - meaning 2nd thread can run for more time than the timeout mentioned in Future because its timeout time starts only after 1st Future's timeout. How to terminate a thread from within itself doing a self-monitoring for timeout or any other external mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Use `THREAD_POOL.invokeAll` instead of `submit` to wait 10s for the tasks to complete.

If some of the tasks have completed before 10 seconds pass, you can check for that with `future.isDone()` and retrieve the result without blocking using `future.get`.

Comment: What you suggested is the timeout if `at least one task` takes more than the timeout. I may often get one of the tasks to be long running. Because of that I don't want to reject the results of other short running tasks. What I need is a timeout for each individual task and ignore the results of only the long running timed-out tasks - and need this individual timeout to be absolute and not relative as in `Future.get()`. This ensures overall time taken is also `approximately` less than 10s and more importantly, I can make use of results of short-running tasks as opposed to throwing away all.

Comment: invokeAll will block the main thread until all tasks are done. Let me try with `CountDownLatch` in main thread with a timeout after `submit`-ing all callable tasks. Iterate and check `future.isDone` and `get` only `isDone` is true.

Comment: I'm talking about this one: `invokeAll(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`

Comment: I thought if `invokeAll` times-out, I will lose all results. But will the long-running thread (DB read query in a DB-Infra jar library over which I have no control) stop immediately after timeout? I guess, No and have to handle interrupt explicitly. If it is a loop, interrupt can be checked every iteration. But if the thread is waiting for a DB read result, how to achieve interrupt? It will be an issue because my `ExecutorService` \ `ThreadPool` will reach its limits soon (So I have to create a big ThreadPool size ?).

Comment: You don't lose the results. See javadocs of `invokeAll(Collection,long,TimeUnit`, specifically:
returns a list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list. If the operation did not time out, each task will have completed. If it did time out, some of these tasks will not have completed.

Comment: you can then cancel any unfinished task with `cancel(true);` 
This will lead to `Thread.interrupt` being called. If the thread is currently blocking and waiting for I/O. Please read the javadocs of `Thread.interrupt` carefully as this might or might not solve your problem.

Comment: `invokeAll` with timeout option cancels timed-out tasks itself from within its own implementation and need not be cancelled or interrupted explicitly. But still the thread which is blocked for DB operation has to 'comply/respond' to the interrupt signal. Once DB call is made, control goes out of my code and interrupt signal cannot be checked for until DB operation is complete and so there is no use of interrupt here. Or is there any example to gracefully exit/remove a thread that waits for a database read operation ?

Comment: Only way is to have an estimate of requests per second and how many threads may get blocked per second and choose a threadpool which is relatively more in size such that threadpool does not get exhausted and blocks subsequent requests.

Comment: all you can do from the outside is cancel the tasks (and you are right, invokeAll with timeout will do that for you) and hope for the best.
If the DB operation is waiting for I/O it will be interrupted though. How the DB connector reacts to that is probably something you have to test. It may re-try or throw an exception.
In general, you can't kill a thread. 
BTW, this is one of the reasons people switch to fully async I/O systems like netty/vert.x which don't have to deal with blocked threads.